# Writing out list items to csv row by row

Tags: python, csv

I have a list with lots of urls in it that I want to write to a csv row by row.

e.g.

```
links = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com']

for word in links:
    f = open('links.csv', 'wb')
    csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n').writerows([word])
    f.close()
```

But this puts them all in their own column like this:

```
http://www.google.com,'http://www.google.com',,'http://www.google.com',,'http://www.google.com',etc
```

(e.g. in Excel they occupy cells A1,B1,C1,D1, etc.)

Instead of row by row beneath each other, i.e. cells A1,A2,A3,A4,A5... etc.

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is the **exact** content of the file based on your code? It doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you've asked it to do. To accomplish what you want I would do:

```
links = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com']
with open("links.csv", "wb") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(links))
```

Comment: The f.write line gives me error:    TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: Then you are doing something that you haven't shared with us. I have tested this and found it to work.

Comment: the list has been appended to multiple times but that's all... i've tested your code and it does work on another script though so thanks!